# Why would a mixer output a signal when only LO is present and RF input is terminated?

Tags: rf, mixer

I have a mixer with a liner frequency sweep going into the LO port, and a terminator on the RF port. I've noticed that this produces a significant signal at the output. It resembles what we would get by applying a time delayed version of the LO to the rf port. I think I already understand the problem is just "LO RF isolation", but I would like to know what physical mechanisms lead to this, how you might simulate it, and what methods are used to deal with it, as it is a problem in high sensitivity systems. When the LO has some phase noise or spurious components, it becomes something you cannot easily remove digitally.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: What kind of mixer? The actual detailed mechanism is going to be different depending on the mixer technology and topology.

Comment: Qs:
what physical mechanisms lead to lo reaching the rf input, what parasitic component might you add to a sim?
What mixers or other solutions do people use to avoid this problem?

Comment: For type of mixers, I have tried 3 that were laying around in our lab. Don't have any of the pn right now sorry. Was operating around 2ghz, and only looking at output below 100mhz

Answer (score 0):

> *Why would a mixer output a signal when only LO is present and RF input
> is terminated?*

and

> *I would like to know what physical mechanisms lead to this, how you
> might simulate it, and what methods are used to deal with it*

If there are DC offsets in the signal paths you can get bleed-through of the local oscillator because, at its heart, this type of mixer is a signal multiplier and, DC multiplied by AC equals a different value of AC.

- You can simulate this by multiplying two inputs and adding DC offsets to both inputs.
- You can deal with it by applying DC offset voltage correction to the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If a mixer is a perfect multiplier then if the rf input is zero then the product should also be zero and if not can be corrected as indicated in Andy's answer.

One reason for using the word mixer is that the non-linear mechanisms used to perform the multiplication also produces other frequencies in addition to the one desired.

This requires the use of a filter to select the desired frequency.

If the rf input is terminated then the non-linear mixer would leak the local oscillator frequency along with some harmonics.